# Go to definition is not working with docker and vagrant

Tags: python, django, docker, visual-studio-code, vagrant

I have a project running on a docker container and another running on a vagrant machine, when I try in to go to definition in that two projects, I receive this message ex: "No definition found for 'BaseUserManager'. ", for all plugins that I have installed on that machines I get the same message.

PS: Go to definition just work on my local workspace.

can you guys help me to solve this problem please?, I really like vscode and I don't wanna quit the editor because of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The source has to be local for the extensions to be able to read the files to analyze the source.

Comment: could you be more precise? I have the source code inside the container through the --volume option (connecting a folder in my local machine to one inside the container). Yet, It seems that I cannot use the "Go to Definition" and all the rest such as "Go to Declaration" in VSCODE

Comment: Everything has to be reachable from the same file system and configured appropriately to know where to look for source code.